# What are the most often used questionnaires in psychology?

Tags: measurement, big-five

As the title says, I am wondering which questionnaires are most often used in psychology.

My guess is that NEO-PI-R should be in the Top-10. One of the accompanying papers has been cited 38k times (https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=en&user=UTRJOukAAAAJ&citation_for_view=UTRJOukAAAAJ:MIg0yeAD4ggC).

Then I guess clinical psychology will dominate, something like the BDI maybe? Citation count is about 11k, https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=bdi&btnG=

Is there any way besides the citation count to get an idea of how often questionnaires are used? It does not have to be very accurate.

There is a similar post here [Update list of the most used and reliable quantitative tests in Psychology](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/26544/update-list-of-the-most-used-and-reliable-quantitative-tests-in-psychology) for which the IPIP is one answer. But the IPIP is, at least so far, not as popular as proprietary instruments (NEO-PI-R). See citation counts for IPIP-NEO-120: https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=ipip-neo-120&btnG=